# Is it possible to track history when browsing in tor under l3 authentication system of college?

Tags: authentication

My college has recently started to use l3 authentication, the one in which you have to login each time to access the internet. This has enabled them to collect logs for each individual user.

Is it possible for them to collect logs if the user is browsing through tor.

Answer (score 0):

No, Tor encrypts your connection and routes it through multiple nodes so your college would just see a bunch of encrypted data going to a Tor node.

See the Tor overview https://2019.www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en

If you mean if they can see a copy of your browsing history stored on your disk, then no as the Tor Browser is designed not to store any records of your browsing history.

https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#disk-avoidance